# Readjusting one plot from a two-plots graph

Tags: r

I have two plots in the same graph. I need to adjust the first plot so that the y axis is in function of the number of cases (which is lower than for the second plot). As for now the first plot is difficult to read because it is much smaller than the second one. I would want it to be proportional.

```
 all.scores = rbind(UK_Together.scores, YesScotland.scores)
 ggplot(data=all.scores) + # ggplot works on data.frames, always
  geom_bar(mapping=aes(x=score, fill=Parti), binwidth=1) +
  facet_grid(Parti~.) + # make a separate plot for each hashtag
  theme_bw() + scale_fill_brewer() # plain display, nicer colors
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: Can you provide a small example dataset? For example, `head(all.scores)`.

Comment: I guess you want `facet_grid(Parti~., scales = "free_y")`?

Comment: This is conceptually very easy to think about, but hard to do in practice. What you could do is "fix" x axis for both plots (breaks and labels in scale_x_discrete, or whichever you use), turn on/off legends, titles... etc for both plots and try to align them using `grid.arrange` in `gridExtra` package.

Comment: Another option would be to combine all your data into a single data.frame and plot using existing `facet_wrap` or `facet_grid` functions.